# merge all tar files on mac

Tags: macos, tar

I have a bunch of tar files such as a.tar b.tar. I use the following command to merge two tar files :

```
tar --concatenate --file=a.tar b.tar
```

However, --concatenate is not support on mac terminal 10.7.4 . What I need to do ?

Comment: try `tar --file=Merged.tar --create file1.txt file2.txt` and tell me if that is what you're looking for. If it is, post back and i will explain what i just showed you. This is basically how you make a "tar ball"

Comment: check my edit ? this was helpful @AlanTuring

Comment: it should still hold true for tar files, give it a swirl. Do you want me to post an answer?

Answer (score 3):

There's a wonderful notion in the tar realm called a tar-ball. Basically it behaves very much the same way a real tarball would. It's sticky and you can throw stuff at it and it will stick!

So the basic Tar usage is:

`tar --file=path_to_tarball  --subcommand [--subcommand] \
         [path_to_payload [path_to_payload]]`

now let's see it in an example.

`tar --file=Merged.tar --create file1.txt file2.txt`

This creates a tarball of the 2 files file1 and file2. As i said earlier you can throw things at the tarball and it will still be fine!

`tar --file=Merged.tar --append file3.txt`

So as you can see the tarball just gets bigger and bigger!

Since you can imagine this to be a rather big ball lying around after some time, perhaps you want to retrieve something from it after a while? Or maybe even delete it?

To extract a file out of the tar ball we have

`tar --file=Merge.tar --extract fileX.txt`

and to delete it

`tar --file=Megre.tar --delete fileX.txt`

for a list of other awesome things you can do with the tar tool, head on over to [MacTech](http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.23/23.10/ArchivingwithTar/index.html)

Comment: +1 thanks AlanTuring for the link and some helpful stuff

Comment: you aint going to accept it lol?